# SAS PROC export to excel and save format

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have SAS guide output.
I want to PROC export him, the problem is that when i export him to excel
All the format changes.

When   I use in the SAS guide the "export as step in the..." everything is ok.

But  I need the PROC export

**So , how can I  export and save all of the format ?**

Thanks

Comment: Please review the guidelines on how to ask a question. This question is unclear, and I have no idea what 'him' refers to. Data typically doesn't have a gender. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
PROC EXPORT DATA= WORK.data
        OUTFILE= "c:\your_path\OutputFileName" 
        DBMS=XLS LABEL REPLACE;
        NEWFILE=YES; 
RUN;
```

For more on proc export see http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n045uxf7ll2p5on1ly4at3vpd47e.htm